# DataTable child rows aren't showing up

Tags: jquery, datatables

I tried using the child rows feature from DataTables, but I'm doing something wrong, not sure what. (I'm new to DataTables)
I'm trying to add some static child rows, just to see it's working (no AJAX).
Clicking on the first column just adds the 'shown' class to the row, but no child row is added.

Also, no error is thrown.

I followed their example from [here](https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html), removing the AJAX data. 
I know it doesn't make any sense in my example (clicking an icon and showing the table from that link), but I just want to go in small steps.

This is what I've got for now:

HTML:

```
<table id='<%= league.name %>' class="event-table display responsive no-wrap">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="event-badge"></th>
            <th class="event-shirt"></th>
            <th class="event-team"></th>
            <th class="event-dash"></th>
            <th class="event-team"></th>
            <th class="event-shirt"></th>
            <th class="event-badge"></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <% events.each do |event| %>
              <tr class="event-row">
                <td class="event-badge"><%= image_tag event.home_team.badge_url, :class => 'team-badge' %></td>
                <td class="event-shirt"><%= image_tag event.home_team.shirt_url, :class => 'team-shirt' %></td>
                <td class="event-team"><%= event.home_team.name %></td>
                <td class="event-dash"> - </td>
                <td class="event-team"><%= event.away_team.name %></td>
                <td class="event-shirt"><%= image_tag event.away_team.shirt_url, :class => 'team-shirt' %></td>
                <td class="event-badge"><%= image_tag event.away_team.badge_url, :class => 'team-badge' %></td>
              </tr>
          <% end %>
          </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var table = $('.event-table').DataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "columns": [
        {
            "className": "details-control",
            "data": "badge-home"
        },
        {
            "data": "shirt-home"
        },
        {
            "data": "name-home"
        },
        {
            "data": "dash"
        },
        {
            "data": "name-away"
        },
        {
            "data": "shirt-away"
        },
        {
            "data": "badge-away"
        }
    ]
});

$('.event-table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format() ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );

function format ( ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Full name:</td>'+
    '<td>Something</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
    '<td>Something</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
    '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
```

**UPDATE**

I did not specify that I had multiple such tables on the same page. Only one was visible. The child rows are actually added but on the wrong table. 
This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4nze1tf/) shows the behaviour
How can I know what table to add the rows to?

Comment: I don't see anything that matches the `td.details-control` selector in your code.

Comment: When I initialise the DataTable I am adding the 'details-control' class to the first column. Check the call at the beginning of the JS code.

Comment: There's probably something up with how you're populating the data because https://jsfiddle.net/xe18dh1u/ is working for me (with placeholder data).

Comment: Your fiddle just made me realise I have a problem because I have 2 such tables on the same page (one is hidden). I added a second table in your html and it seems like the child rows are being added to the second one. (which in my case was hidden). How can I solve this?

Comment: This is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u4nze1tf/ (with 2 tables).

Comment: There should be a way to get the real reference of the dataTables object via the API, since the table variable will probably have the object only for the 2nd table. I've made an update to the fiddle that kind-of solves the problem, but it's not a very elegant solution (since an API call is probably better). https://jsfiddle.net/u4nze1tf/1/

Comment: I'll update the question so you can post the answer. It's working now. I had another issue, I sometimes had 2 tables with the same id, because I had tables from the same league but from different days.(so I now apped the day in the id as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be referring to the table object created by DataTables. However if you have multiple tables initialized by the same call, your table object will only refer to one of those tables (with unpredictable results). Your best bet is to store a reference on each of those table objects in the table data.

Rewrite the initialization part like so:

```
$(.event-table).each(function () { 
var table = $(this).DataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "columns": [
        {
            "className": "details-control",
            "data": "badge-home"
        },
        {
            "data": "shirt-home"
        },
        {
            "data": "name-home"
        },
        {
            "data": "dash"
        },
        {
            "data": "name-away"
        },
        {
            "data": "shirt-away"
        },
        {
            "data": "badge-away"
        }
    ]
});
$(this).data("dataTableObject", table);
});
$('.event-table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var table = $(this).closest(".event-table").data("dataTableObject");
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format() ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );

function format ( ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Full name:</td>'+
    '<td>Something</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
    '<td>Something</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
    '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
    '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
```

Example fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/u4nze1tf/1/